# Can't use the Scanner class

Tags: java

I just started studying JAVA. I'm trying something very simple: Request a argument from the user on the prompt. I made this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Request
{ 
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("What's your name?");
      String name = s.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Welcome " + name);
  }
}
```

then I compile it, and when I execute it with

```
Java -cp Request
```

Instead of a prompt expecting a parameter
It prints all the options of the JAVA command as if I had coded this:

```
java -help
```

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `java Request`, or maybe `java -cp . Request` ; the `-cp` option provides the JVM with a classpath, which should be a list of jars or directories containing `.class` files.

As Klitos mentions, you can set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable to provide a default classpath. Setting it to include the current directory `.` is common practice and spare you from having to use `-cp .` when invoking Java.

In Windows, the variable is `%CLASSPATH%` and is a `;`-separated list of windows pathes.
In Linux (and MacOS AFAIK), the variable is `$CLASSPATH` and is a `:`-separated list of unix pathes.

Comment: Stupid error, thank you. I tried with no success, to use the Java command without the -cp with it. I readed lots of tutorials but nothing worked. The Java command always work but without the cp it never find the class. So I kinda must use the -cp.

Comment: @FernandoAnaelCabral Check your CLASSPATH environment variable. If it's set to directory x, then Java will only look in directory x for class files. When you supply -cp on the command line, you override the CLASSPATH variable. To avoid having to use -cp every time, remove the CLASSPATH variable or, if you need it, add . (the current directory) to it. Separate directories with ':' on Linux/OSX and ';' on Windows.